# Invalid SSL master secret in Jenkins with AWS Cloudfromation

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-cloudformation, jenkins-plugins

I'm running a job using the cloud formation plugin and until today I get this error

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid SSL master secret
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.verifyMasterSecret(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:143)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:461)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:296)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudformation.AmazonCloudFormationClient.invoke(AmazonCloudFormationClient.java:1273)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudformation.AmazonCloudFormationClient.describeStacks(AmazonCloudFormationClient.java:385)
    at com.syncapse.jenkinsci.plugins.awscloudformationwrapper.CloudFormation.create(CloudFormation.java:198)
    at com.syncapse.jenkinsci.plugins.awscloudformationwrapper.CloudFormationBuildStep.perform(CloudFormationBuildStep.java:90)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:47)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:806)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:198)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:514)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1888)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:431)
Build step 'AWS Cloud Formation' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I validated my secret and private keys and also the node where I'm running the job have installed AWS CLI

Does someone know something about the error?

Just I cloud found the below: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/tls-1-3-incompatibility-with-aws-sdk-for-java-versions-1-9-5-to-1-10-31/

But this no makes sense for me, could be related with the plugin, a bug